# Flutter: Ensure Text is perfectly centred when there are more items on one side?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In a `Row`, how can I ensure that the `Text` with "Hello" in it is perfectly centered and not a bit to the left when the right most inner `Row` widget has more items than the left most inner `Row` widget?

Notice in the screenshot that the "Hello" is slight to the left.

I tried using a `Stack` but that seems to not work well if the text is longer than the available space as it causes the text to then overlap the side-colored widgets.

I am using the following code:

```
Center(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 45,
            height: 45,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Text(
        "Hello",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 45,
            height: 45,
            color: Colors.purple,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 45,
            height: 45,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: *perfectly centered* to the screen width ?

Comment: @sudoExclaimationExclaimation are those other widget have specific width?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh perfectly centred to the parent Row width.

Comment: @eamirho3ein no, the other widgets can have dynamic width.

Comment: I think OMI Shah's answer will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap both the `Row`s and the `Text` widget, children of the first `Row` widget, with the `Expanded` widget and set the `mainAxisAlignmnet` of the right `Row` to `MainAxisAlignment.end`.

```
Center(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 45,
              height: 45,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      const Expanded(
        child: Text(
          "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 45,
              height: 45,
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 45,
              height: 45,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Output:

[image] [image]

---

If either of the sides will have more widget's then you can use the `Wrap` widget instead of the inner `Row` widgets which will wrap the overflowing items to the next line.

```
Center(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Wrap(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 45,
              height: 45,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      const Expanded(
        child: Text(
          "Ex qui tempor dolore ex aliquip ex consectetur proident excepteur eu. Velit non sint laboris sit. Ut minim proident irure non ullamco deserunt qui. Quis eu tempor consequat amet irure consequat irure elit. Culpa id in laboris reprehenderit veniam voluptate tempor minim eu reprehenderit sit.",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 45,
              height: 45,
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 45,
              height: 45,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 45,
              height: 45,
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 45,
              height: 45,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if the text is long. Then it overflows and pushes the side widgets off the screen.

Comment: @sudoExclaimationExclaimation as I already mentioned in the post that if the text is long, you had to just wrap the text widget with the expanded widget and it should have worked !! Though, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again - it breaks and shows an "Overflow" message if the right side has more than 2 widgets. Do you know why?

Comment: Obviously it'll since, all the 3 widgets, which are wrapped by the Expanded widget, will take equal widths and if any one of them tries taking more space than the allocated space, will end up showing overflow due to constraints!

Comment: @sudoExclaimationExclaimation, if either of the sides will have more widget's then you can use the ``Wrap`` widget instead of the inner ``Row`` widgets which will wrap the overflowing items to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a specific code that might suit your case, here is the result first:

[image]

basically, the idea of it is to get the width of both rows in corners, then search for the `max` within between them, then set the `Text()` width to the screen width size, minus that max multiplied by two, this ensures that it will be exactly in the center and not overlapping the widgets:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'controllers/controller.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

double firstRowWidth = 0;
double secondRowWidth = 0;
double max = 0;

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  TestPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  final testController = Get.put(TestController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPersistentFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        setState(() {
          max = math.max(secondRowWidth, firstRowWidth);
        });
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                row2(),
                row1(),
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - (max * 2),
              child: Text(
                "Hello" * 20,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class row1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const row1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      firstRowWidth = context.size!.width;
    });
    return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 45,
          height: 45,
          color: Colors.purple,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 45,
          height: 45,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class row2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const row2({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      secondRowWidth = context.size!.width;
    });
    return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 45,
          height: 45,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: This seems fairly complex for something simple but it does work. So I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have other widget width you can use `stack` widget:

```
Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 45,
                height: 45,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 45,
                height: 45,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 45,
                height: 45,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      Text(
        "Hello",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

If your text is long, I recommend @OMiShah answer and wrap your text with `expanded` widget.

[image]

Comment: this is a clean solution but this will overlap with the other widgets as pointed by the OP.  AW, UV ;)

Comment: @yes I didn't see that.

Comment: Yes, I already tried this solution but it causes widgets to be overlapped if the text is long.

Answer (score 0):

try the following, I made it with the `Stack` widget:
[image]

```
Center(
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 45,
                height: 45,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 45,
                height: 45,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 45,
                height: 45,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      Text(
        "Hello",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but it causes widgets to be overlapped if the text is long as I pointed out in my post.