# How to center a widget, and put left another in the same row?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Goal is to center first widget and put to left second widget. However, if centered widget is too long, it should wrap, not overlap on left widget. That's why Stack is not working.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("Center me"),
                Text("I am left"),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [Text("Not very centered")]
                  ),
                ),
                Text("I am left"),
              ],
            ),
            Stack(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [Text("Center me, I should wrap because I am too loooooooooooooong ")],
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right: 0,
                  child: Text("I am left"),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I think it's a very basic common used UI, it would be nice to have some sort of `MainAxisAligment.centerAndLeft` or some `Flexible`  extension for this.

(The trick that I am currently using to make this work is to have left widget in a variable and put it on both side, then use `spaceBetween` , and make Opacity to zero for the right one, but it is an overkill, and reduce available space if the left widget is too long)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Ensure Text is perfectly centred when there are more items on one side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74507125/flutter-ensure-text-is-perfectly-centred-when-there-are-more-items-on-one-side)

Comment: No, the accepted answer uses 3 Expanded, that's just dividing the amount of space equally between the 3 widget. This OP of the question does not address the overlapping issue

Comment: try [CustomBoxy](https://pub.dev/documentation/boxy/latest/boxy/CustomBoxy-class.html)

Comment: and btw, does the height of such "row" depends on its two children? or it is fixed by a parent?

Answer (score 1):

Cache your text widget into a local variable:

```dart
Widget textWidget = Text("I am left");
```

And put the text variable to build method and wrap with visibility widget below:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    // put the cached text widget to add some equal space
    // and set visibility to false and set some property
    // below to maintain its size with Visibility widget
    Visibility(
      visible: false,
      maintainSize: true,
      maintainAnimation: true,
      maintainState: true,
      child: textWidget,
    ),
    const Expanded(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text("Now very centered"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    // put the cached text widget
    textWidget,
  ],
),
```

The complete code:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // cache the text widget
    Widget textWidget = Text("I am left");

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text("Not very centered"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("I am left"),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  // put the cached text widget to add some equal space
                  // and set visibility to false and set some property
                  // below to maintain its size with Visibility widget
                  Visibility(
                    visible: false,
                    maintainSize: true,
                    maintainAnimation: true,
                    maintainState: true,
                    child: textWidget,
                  ),
                  const Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text("Now very centered"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  // put the cached text widget
                  textWidget,
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So Adan kinda did what you want but I think you wanted something like if text is too long it should go to the left side. So I added some stuff to Adan's code. Let me explain what I did.

I added centerText to an element because I assume that the information will come from backend. I added a LayoutBuilder widget to the Expanded so that I can get the box's constraints. In the initState method, I called `checkOverflow` after rendering done. That code will create a TextSpan with TextPainter so normally how much space as width that Text element will get. After that if it does, it will set the state and the Visible element will be gone, your text will still centered but that will take much more space. If the text exceeeds that too, then it will became '...'

This is the full code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final String centerText = 'Now very centered';
  late BoxConstraints constraints;

  bool isOverflow = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      checkOverflow(context, constraints);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    // if text is not overflow make it centered with the same
                    // text widget element. If there is an overflow make this
                    // widget not showable so Expanded can grow
                    if (!isOverflow)
                      const Visibility(
                        visible: false,
                        maintainAnimation: true,
                        maintainState: true,
                        maintainSize: true,
                        child: Text('I am left'),
                      ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: LayoutBuilder(
                        builder: (context, constraints) {
                          this.constraints = constraints;

                          return Container(
                            color: Colors.amber,
                            child: Text(
                              centerText,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    // put the cached text widget
                    const Text('I am left'),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  checkOverflow(BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    // Build the textspan
    var span = TextSpan(
      text: centerText,
    );

    // Use a textpainter to determine if it will exceed max lines
    var tp = TextPainter(
      maxLines: 1,
      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      text: span,
    );

    // trigger it to layout
    tp.layout(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);

    // whether the text overflowed or not
    var exceeded = tp.didExceedMaxLines;
    debugPrint(exceeded.toString());

    setState(() {
      isOverflow = exceeded;
    });
  }
}
```

These are the examples:
Short Text
[image]

Long Text No Overflow
[image]

Long Text With Overflow
[image]

I hope this is what you wanted. Happy coding!!!